# How to move body out of collision on Farseer + Monogame?

Tags: collision-detection, monogame, farseer

I'm making a game where I have a Kinematic body that needs to move next to a Dynamic body when it stops. Now let's assume that I have the following scenario:

[image]

The black line is my terrain, the blue circle is my dynamic body and the red rectangle is the kinematic body that follows the circle. What currently happens to me is the scenario on A (since I simply move the rectangle body next to the circle) and what I want is B. I have no idea on how to do this.

I'm working on Xamarin with Farseer and Monogame libraries.

Comment: Maybe some kind of ray casting into the floor?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little new to this. You mean to do a RayCast between the red Rectangle and the Fixture of the ground and then use the resulting Vector of the Raycast to position the rectangle correctly?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I actually haven't done it myself but I've seen a few tutorials that go along those lines. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't know exactly what to search for and now at least I know that Raycasting might help :)